# Let $A = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2011}+\frac{1}{2012}+\frac{1}{2013}+\frac{1}{2014}+\frac{1}{2015}+\frac{1}{2016}}$.

Tags: inequality, fractions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $A =  \cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{2011}+\cfrac{1}{2012}+\cfrac{1}{2013}+\cfrac{1}{2014}+\cfrac{1}{2015}+\cfrac{1}{2016}}$. $B$ is the largest integer so that $B \le A$. Find $B$

I tried to use AM-GM inequality in the denominator but it is impossible

Comment: [Here's a calculator](https://web2.0calc.com/)

Comment: Big Hint: $2011 < 6A < 2016$ (why?) so $335 < A < 336,$ making $B=335$

Comment: @Shaun I've edit that

Comment: @amrsa I don't need the answer, just how to solve it

Comment: @TranTu Follow BrianMoehring's lead...

Comment: @MartinR this is a duplicate, what do I do? Sorry for not searching question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2011} + \frac{1}{2011} + \frac 1{2011} + \frac{1}{2011}+\frac{1}{2011}+\frac{1}{2011}}  < \frac 1{\frac{1}{2011} +\frac{1}{2012} +\frac{1}{2013} +\frac{1}{2014} +\frac{1}{2015} +\frac{1}{2016}}\\ < \frac{1}{\frac 1{2016}+\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2016}}
$$

LHS $=  \frac {2011}{6} > 335$ , RHS $= \frac {2016} {6} = 336$